# bash script to login to webpage

Tags: bash, login, scripts, curl

I am trying to login into [this page](https://campus.fsu.edu) but I cannot for the life of me get it to work. I have to login to this site when i connect to my school's wifi in order to start a session.

So far ive tried to use bash and cUrl to achieve this but have only achieved to give myself a headache. will cUrl work or am I on the wrong track? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

N

Here's what i tried:

```
curl --cookie-jar cjar --output /dev/null http://campus.fsu.edu/webapps/login/

curl --cookie cjar --cookie-jar cjar \
    --data 'username=foo' \
    --data 'password=bar' \
    --data 'service=http://campus.fsu.edu/webapps/login/' \
    --data 'loginurl=http://campus.fsu.edu/webapps/login/bb_bb60/logincas.jsp' \
    --location \
    --output ~/loginresult.html \
        http://campus.fsu.edu/webapps/login/
```

Comment: Could you post the code you tried to use to login to that webpage? Also I think bash isn't the way you wanna do this I'm not even sure if there's a way to do this in bash. Sounds like a job for Perl or JavaScript maybe? I'm just starting to learn the basics of programming myself though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way to bash login:

```
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --post-data="username=foo&password=bar" "http://some.site/login.php"
```

Although some websites may have some restrictions to login like this.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this even in Yahoo prompt bash ... you will get a login accepted

```
curl --user name:password http://mail.yahoo.com -v
```

curl is the way to do it in bash.